# Mixed style page in Hugo (my content + list of products)

Tags: html, hugo

I'm writing a Hugo site where I need to have a products page with some html and then a list of items below. But, I'm not able to access the .Params for that html content that I want to put before the list.

The content folder is populated with these files:

```
.
├── index.md
└── products
    ├── index.md
    ├── product_1.md
    └── product_2.md
```

The layouts folder is populated with these files:

```
.
├── index.html
└── products
    ├── product_block_item.html (/products iterates through this content)
    ├── products.html (for /products)
    └── single.html (for /products/product_x)
```

Here is my products.html:

```
{{ partial "header.html" . }}
  <div class="container">
    <section class="products" id="products">

        <div>
            <div class="slider-text">{{ .Params.banner_title }}</div>
            <img src="{{ .Params.banner_path }}" style="width:100%;">
        </div>

        <div class="grid products-view-grid">
            <div class="tab-content center">
                {{ range .Data.Pages }}
                    {{ .Render "product_block_item" }}
                {{ end}}
            </div>          
        </div>      

    </section>
  </div>
{{ partial "footer.html" . }}
```

If I create the products/index.md with the banner_path and the banner_title params, the list of products is not render, Hugo might not be able to find them.

If I remove the products/index.md file, then the list is rendered, but then the .Params.banner_path and .Params.banner_title are gone...

Is there a way to solve this problem?